# Highchart from select rows in HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, highcharts

I have an HTML table that contains dynamically generated values. This is what it looks like on page load:
http://jsfiddle.net/HE8Vj/

The first column of the HTML table contains check boxes. I want the **pie chart** that is generated from the HTML table to ONLY contain the rows on the HTML table whose check box has been checked.

I am using **Highcharts** library for the pie chart.

I have managed to get the code partially working.
When checkboxes in row (1) or (1,2) or (1,2,3) or (1,2,3,4) are selected, the pie chart is generated properly.

But when that proper order is changed, like when a row is skipped, eg: row (2) or (2,3,4) or (1,3,4) or (4), the console pops an error and the pie chart is not generated.

**Here is the** [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/W5asQ/1/)

This has been bugging me for quite some time.

*Small code segment:*

```
                            if ($('#check'+i).is(':checked'))
                            {
                                console.log(i);
                                options.series[0].data[i-1].push(this.innerHTML);

                            }
```

Thanks!

Edit: Here is the entire file (no additional files needed to run it) - http://pastebin.com/nhr4Q0fm

Comment: Your fiddle is not working ! It does not contain JS code !

Comment: I only meant to show the table on fiddle.

Comment: But you should create a working fiddle of what you have tried so far and upto how extent your code is working ! So that it can give a clear idea of on what stage you are stuck !

Comment: I have little experience with fiddle and don't know how to run my code on it. Here is my file instead: http://pastebin.com/nhr4Q0fm

Sorry for being inexperienced. Will experiment with fiddle later :)

Comment: I have created a JSFIDDLE demo and added the link to it in your question. Please work out the demo for the error resolution as far as you can and then if you are stuck somewhere then let me know !

Comment: Please also provide the link to some similar reference examples of Highcharts if there are any !

Comment: Thanks a lot for your trouble. There's a small problem though- when I run my code, the checkboxes (as long as any number of them are checked in order) the pie chart works. But in your JSFiddle, the chart will only generate if all the boxes are checked.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Let me edit the code in Fiddle. - Update- fiddle is working with the most updated version now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you were overkilling it a little so here's what it looks like now:

```
// Here we iterate on each of the returned selectors (checked inputs)
$.each($(':checked'), function (index, item) {
    // item is the checked input
    //First we get a jQuery reference to the 'item', then we chain the 'parents' method with an argument of 'tr' meaning: get all parents of this 'item' which are a 'tr' element.  Then we get only the first returned on using 'first()' method, then get that returned elements 'children' who are 'td'.
    var tds = $(item).parents('tr').first().children('td');
    // Since we now should have a collection/array of all 'td' in the 'tr' of the ':checked' input we can iterate through the array. Since tds[0] would be the first one in the row, that is where the checked input lives.  Thus tds[1] and tds[2] are 'name' and 'project' respectively.
    var name = $(tds[1]).html();
    var projects = parseFloat($(tds[2]).html());
    // Now we just push the two values as an array
    options.series[0].data.push([name, projects]);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/W5asQ/2/

Comment: Thank you! Nicely done! May I know what 'tds' stands for? Thanks!

Comment: it stands for the plural of `TD` as in table cell `<td>` since were getting a reference to all the cells of the row.

Comment: Could you go into a little more detail on how you get the reference to the row. 

var tds = $(item).parents('tr').first().children('td');

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're only entering data into an array when the input is checked here:

```
if (j == 1) {
    if ($('#check'+i).is(':checked'))
    {
        console.log(i);
        options.series[0].data[i-1].push(this.innerHTML);
        //alert('selected label: ' + this.innerHTML);
    };
}
```

Which means that whenever `$('#check'+i)` is unchecked, you leave that `.data[i-1]` in the array as `undefined`, which the Highcharts.Chart library doesn't understand. You should add a blank, zero, or " " value in those instances:

```
if (j == 1) {
    if ($('#check'+i).is(':checked'))
    {
        console.log(i);
        options.series[0].data[i-1].push(this.innerHTML);
        //alert('selected label: ' + this.innerHTML);
    }else{
        options.series[0].data[i-1].push(" ");
    }
}
```

Make sure you also enter a value of 0 when `j == 2`, or you'll run into the same error.

Comment: I just tried this but the console pops the same error. "TypeError: options.series[0].data[(i - 1)] is undefined"

Comment: Here is the entire code if you need to see it. (No other files are needed to run it): http://pastebin.com/nhr4Q0fm